# Winforms binding question

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, collections

I am relatively new to binding in win forms. In order to learn the subject I setup the following test application. A basic winform with a `ListBox` and a `Button`.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public List<String> stringList = new List<String>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        stringList.Add("First");
        listBox1.DataSource = stringList;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stringList.Add("Second");
    }
}
```

The string "First" shows in `listBox1` on application launch. However, when I push the button which adds a new string to the `stringList` the new item is not shown in `listBox1`. Could anyone help me understand the basics of collection data binding?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Replace `List<String>` with `BindingList<String>`.

The [BindingList class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) can be used as a base class to create a two-way data-binding mechanism. BindingList provides a concrete, generic implementation of the IBindingList interface.

`List<T>` class does not provide any notification about collection changes. So there is no way `ListBox` would know that a new element is added. However, if you use a collection that implements [IBindingList Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist.aspx), ListBox subscribes to `ListChanged` event. This is how it know when to refresh itself.